# Best way to create form (or any HTML fragments) programmatically with DOM in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, dom

I'm wanting to create a form builder that creates HTML forms programmatically with PHP, but I'm wanting it to be object-orientated. This lead me to looking at PHP's DOM extension, but it seems to work on the concept of full HTML (and XML) documents rather than portions of the DOM.

Therefore, is it possible in PHP to create HTML in an object-orientated way? For example, my pseudo-code may look as follows:

```
<?php

$form = new HTMLElement('form', array('method' => 'post', 'action' => 'contact.php'));

$fieldset = $form->addElement(new HTMLElement('fieldset'));
$fieldset->addElement(new HTMLElement('input', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'name'
)));
$fieldset->addElement(new HTMLElement('input', array(
    'type' => 'email',
    'name' => 'email'
)));
// and so on...

echo $form->asHTML();
```

Comment: I think you can with [DOMDocument](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php). (Note, I updated the first reference.)

Comment: [Tutorial of DOMDocument.](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/php/864-object-oriented-html-generation.html?start=1)

Comment: If you want to make things really OO you should have your form builder have a render for any kind of output including HTML and as well multiple input libraries that can read from different input interfaces, e.g. a HTTP request. How the HTML is generated is pretty uninteresting and should be a pretty straight forward job for the renderer, not needing much "OO".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (requires PHP 5, btw):

```
<?php

$html = new DOMDocument('1.0','iso-8859-1');
$html->formatOutput = true;

$form = $html->createElement('form');

$fieldset = $html->createElement('fieldset');

$name = $html->createElement('input');
$name->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$name->setAttribute('name', 'name');

$email = $html->createElement('input');
$email->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$email->setAttribute('name', 'email');

$fieldset->appendChild($name);
$fieldset->appendChild($email);

$form->appendChild($fieldset);

$html->appendChild($form);

echo html_entity_decode($html->saveHTML());
```

http://codepad.org/sK0j6zD3

Which outputs:

```
<form><fieldset>
<input type="text" name="email"><input type="text">
</fieldset></form>
```

A more complete document:

```
<?php

class br extends DOMElement {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('br');
    }
}

$page = new DOMDocument();
$page->normalizeDocument();
$page->formatOutput = true;

$html = $page->createElement('html');
$head = $page->createElement('head');
$title = $page->createElement('title');
$body = $page->createElement('body');
$form = $page->createElement('form');
$fieldset = $page->createElement('fieldset');
$name = $page->createElement('input');
$email = $page->createElement('input');
$submit = $page->createElement('input');

$title_text = $page->createTextNode('Page Title Here');
$title->appendChild($title_text);

$head->appendChild($title);

$html->appendChild($head);

$name->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$name->setAttribute('name', 'name');

$email->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$email->setAttribute('name', 'email');

$submit->setAttribute('type','submit');
$submit->setAttribute('value','Submit');

$fieldset->appendChild($page->createTextNode('Name: '));
$fieldset->appendChild($name);
$fieldset->appendChild(new br);
$fieldset->appendChild($page->createTextNode('Email: '));
$fieldset->appendChild($email);
$fieldset->appendChild(new br);
$fieldset->appendChild($submit);

$form->appendChild($fieldset);

$body->appendChild($form);

$html->appendChild($body);

$page->appendChild($html);

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" . html_entity_decode($page->saveHTML());
```

http://codepad.org/uRNoW3nN

Which outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Page Title Here</title></head>
<body><form><fieldset>Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset></form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what's creating the new lines in the HTML?  One of my biggest issues creating dynamic HTML is the way it displays in source, always sloppy.

Comment: If you're looking for a specific formatting methodology, I would suggest [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) on the HTML output, as there's not a lot of support for handling whitespace with the DOM classes. See: http://codepad.viper-7.com/KqbLoZ